# Remove words from stopword list

Tags: r, text, text-mining, stop-words

I previously asked a question how to remove words from a stop list in a character vector by keeping the original format. The task was to remove words of "words_to_remove" in the vector "words".
I accepted this solution:

```
words_to_remove = c("the", "This")
pattern <- paste0("\\b", words_to_remove, "\\b", collapse="|")
words = c("the", "The", "Intelligent", "this", "This")

res <- grepl(pattern, words, ignore.case=TRUE)
words[!res]
```

Now I have the problem that I have multiple words in an entry of "words". Then the whole entry is deleted if it contains a stop word.

```
words = c("the", "The Book", "Intelligent", "this", "This")
```

I receive the output

```
[1] "Intelligent"
```

but I want it to be

```
[1] "Book"   "Intelligent"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Use `gsub` instead of `grepl`. Replace the words with a space.

Comment: Try `gsub(paste(words_to_remove, collapse = '|'), '', words, ignore.case = TRUE)`

Comment: @ WinterMensch, see my first comment to Tim's answer in your previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `gsub`, i.e.

```
v1 <- gsub(paste(words_to_remove, collapse = '|'), '', words, ignore.case = TRUE)

#Tidy up your output

trimws(v1)[v1 != '']
#[1] "Book"        "Intelligent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the pattern to

```
pattern <- paste0("^", words_to_remove, "$", collapse="|")
```

to include start and end of string markers, rather than just word boundaries. The rest of your code should work fine with this one change.